# tools to modify generated svg paths

Tags: html, svg, svg-path

I have this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d8r4wcj/1/).

This is basically a SVG with animation. As seen in the text it says "Introducing Canadian Crude Oil Index ETF". I want to change it to be "Introducing Canadian Oil and GAS ETFs".

Obviously, I can play around with the numbers in the `d` tag for each letter to change it but that seems like a waste of time. Is there a quick way to do this? Any tools which can generate similar svg or tools that can take this svg and give me the ability to modify it then generate it again?

Comment: You can just use a graphics editor, for example Inkscape. Paste the whole `<svg />` element (or just the opening+closing tag and elements you want to edit) into separate text file, open in Inkscape, edit, save changes, paste back to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.

Comment: Inkscape fails to open the txt file containing <svg>, Should it be in a different format?

Comment: Ya you've got some unclosed group tag or something, hence the error. In reality the designer should have just made the image graphic and used actual text/css to style the words/letters. Wish I had time to help find the exact culprit but that's not a small one, good luck.

Comment: Ya I just took a quick peek, that file has a bunch of problems with open/unclosed <g> group tags. It would take awhile to repair it amigo, sorry.